# NullPointerException when running gradle for the first time on Google AppEngine Standard project

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle

I got a problem when initialising my AppEngine project with gradle. 
I'm using the code as described here [Using Gradle and the App Engine Plugin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/gradle).

Here is the error thrown by Gradle on the first time :

```
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'MemeLib'.
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:80)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:73)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$600(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:53)
        ...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.appengine.flexible.AppEngineFlexiblePlugin$1.execute(AppEngineFlexiblePlugin.java:86)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.appengine.flexible.AppEngineFlexiblePlugin$1.execute(AppEngineFlexiblePlugin.java:79)
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the solution [here](https://github.com/gcpug/nouhau/blob/master/app-engine/note/gradle-plugin-throw-npe/README.md)

My project didn't have the right folder structure: 
For App Engine Standard Java, the `appengine-web.xml` file must be located in the `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` directory and in my project I created the file in `web/WEB-INF/`.